# Combine Rows of Data only if match is found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the example below - Row 229 & 230 are located in the same **New Location**(Column F) with same SKU (Column A). I would like to combine the data ONLY if :-

1. Column A & F are the same(disregard qtys)
2. I would expect to see 1 new Row with the new total for that Sku & Location - A21096 at D07A2 Qty 10
3. There could be up to 5 rows of data that could match Column A & F:

[image: data structure]

Result should be like this:

[image: result structure]

Comment: Can I ask you about the current issue of your script and provide the sample result you expect using your sample input in the image as an image? Unfortunately, I couldn't see the vision of your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Will they always consecutive in the list?

Comment: Tanaike - i updated and put another image. result should look like yellow highlight

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are always consecutive.

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var shsr=2;
  var vs=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var vo=[];
  var d=0;
  for(var i=0;i-d<vs.length;i++) {
    if(i>0 && vs[i-d][0]==vs[i-d-1][0] && vs[i-d][5]==vs[i-d-1][5]){
      vs[i-d][2]=vs[i-d][2]+vs[i-d-1][2];
      vs[i-d][6]=vs[i-d][6]+vs[i-d-1][6];
      vs.splice(i-1-d++,1);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent()
  sh.getRange(shsr,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jim - yes I can filter Column A to have them consecutive

Comment: Jim - I am getting an error. Reference Error: v is not defined line 9

Comment: Try it again.  I used v in place of vs in some places.

Comment: Jim - Unfortunately it deleted the line with the qty of 2. i needed it to add, so result would equal qty 10

Comment: Try this one.  I'm trying to do it a little differently.

Comment: Jim - it just clears content of everything in the spreadsheet

Comment: I think this last version will do it.

Comment: Got It !! - Thanks very much Jim

Comment: Glad  to help.  Hope all is going well for you.

Comment: Jim - yes thank you. very busy here. all your code has been running great and is a huge help

Comment: Hope all is well with you & family